# ProgressBar dosen't load. Android App

Tags: android, android-studio

When I put `ProgressBar` in my android Application I have this:

[image]

Just a Loading animation, instead of the actual `ProgressBar`.

I added the bar like everyother element I have added before (buttons, texts...)
The only thing I specified was Max (=100)

than in code I have these lines

```
private ProgressBar mProgressP1;
```

and in `onCreate()`:

```
    mProgressP1 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
```

and in refresh function (also run during onCreate)

```
 mProgressP1.setProgress(score1);
```

I gotta be missing something very basic! Help me out please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a horizonatal progress bar. Simply add the following style in your android xml.

```
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
```

This is explained clearly in the [Progress Bars developer website](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html).

Comment: Helped indeed! Thank you very much. I wonder why android studio didn't put it for me as it did in all elements I already had in this project!

Answer (score 0):

You are using indeterminate mode.  That is, spinner only, no actual progress indicators.  You need to not do that.  Also, this:

```
        mProgressP1.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
```

will get it to be a horizontal progress bar.

Comment: That's another approach :D 
Thanks as well :)!